# Kernel boot hangs for 12s

Tags: linux, boot, kernel

#### My laptop

Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Extreme

```
# uname -sr
Linux 4.19.66-gentoo
```

#### LiveCD

[SystemRescueCd](http://www.system-rescue-cd.org) v6.0.3
Kernel: linux-4.19.34

#### `dmesg`'s

https://pastebin.com/Lt3ePJhu

```
[    0.651272] PCI: CLS 0 bytes, default 64
[   12.858422] DMAR: Host address width 39
```

`CONFIG_DMAR_TABLE=n` https://pastebin.com/2yCWGKSL

```
[    0.650203] PCI: CLS 0 bytes, default 64
[   12.881594] PCI-DMA: Using software bounce buffering for IO (SWIOTLB)
```

LiveCD https://pastebin.com/k36PrSUF

```
[    0.715791] PCI: CLS 0 bytes, default 64
[    0.715874] Unpacking initramfs...
[    4.514591] Freeing initrd memory: 39588K
[    4.565388] PCI-DMA: Using software bounce buffering for IO (SWIOTLB)
```

#### Kernel configs diff

```
sdiff -s <(zcat /mnt/usb/config-livecd.gz) <(zcat /proc/config.gz)
```

https://filebin.net/4g9c6bnlgur4o6ku/local-livecd.diff.gz

#### Question

How can I proceed further with investigating this 12s lag on Kernel boot?

Comment: You may want to include some additional info (OS, kernel ver, etc), else a moderator may flag it for lacking enough info.  I'm assuming you didn't because of the PasteBin links, however there's no guarantee those links will be available 10 years from now, whereas this question still will be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to bloated initramfs in which I've included all the linux-firmware...

```
# du -hd0 /boot/initramfs.cpio
529M    /boot/initramfs.cpio
```

After trimming it to 70mb initramfs loading takes only 2s:

```
[    0.614545] PCI: CLS 0 bytes, default 64
[    2.640922] DMAR: Host address width 39
```